# DRF nested serialization without raw sql query

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-orm

I've stuck with this problem for few days now. Tried different approaches but without success. I have two classes - Poll and PollAnswer. Here they are:

```
class Poll(Model):
    title = CharField(max_length=256)
```

```
class PollAnswer(Model):
    user_id = CharField(max_length=10)
    poll = ForeignKey(Poll, on_delete=CASCADE)
    text = CharField(max_length=256)
```

what is the right way to get list of polls which have answers with used_id equal to the certain string with nested list of that user's answers? like this:

```
{
    'poll_id': 1,
    'answers' : {
        'user1_answer1: 'answer_text1',
        'user1_answer2: 'answer_text2',
        'user1_answer3: 'answer_text3',    
    },
}
```

and if it's the simple question i probably need some good guides on django orm.

the first thing i tried was to make serializer's method (inherited from drf's ModelSerializer) but got an error that this class can't have such method. after that i tried to use serializer's field with ForeignKey but got polls nested in answers instead. right now i believe i can make Polls.objects.raw('some_sql_query') but that's probably not the best way.

Comment: I think this should be possible using `DictField`, but would require some extra work to create the keys since they're dynamic. Why not make answers an array and have nested objects containing the user ID and answer?

Comment: ah, so i will have a serializer with polls which i can get from PollAnswer.objects.filter(user_id=user_id) and then make a nested field with PollAnswer.objects.filter(poll_id=Poll.id).filter(user_id=user_id)

right?

Comment: I think that sounds right.

Comment: Hi, did you find the answer?

Comment: i didn't try it yet. will try again in a few days.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well, thanks for help the final code is:

serializer:

```
class UserPollsSerializer(ModelSerializer):

    answers = SerializerMethodField()

    # drf automatically finds this method by mask get_{field}
    def get_answers(self, obj):
        answers = self.context.get('answers_qs').filter(poll=obj)
        data = QuestionAnswerSerializer(answers, many=True).data
        return data

    class Meta:
        model = Poll
        fields = '__all__'
```

view:

```
class PollMVS(ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = PollSerializer
    permission_classes = [IsAdminUser]
    queryset = Poll.objects.all()

    # getting polls with answers by user_id
    @action(detail=False, methods=['get'])
    def user_polls(self, request):
        
        # here i get all polls with user's answers
        user_id = request.GET.get('user_id')
        polls_ids = QuestionAnswer.objects.values('poll').filter(user_id=user_id).distinct()
        u_polls = Poll.objects.filter(pk__in=polls_ids)
        
        # and here i pass them as a queryset and answers' queryset as context in a separate serializer
        serializer = UserPollsSerializer(u_polls, many=True, context={'answers_qs': QuestionAnswer.objects.filter(user_id=user_id)})
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is described in documentation (also best practise).
You can use nested serializer:

https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#writable-nested-serializers

otherwise if u want to keep nested answers as you described:
i would use serializer method field

https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializermethodfield

then do a little loop over your answers ... and return whatever format you want to.

Comment: I forgot about `SerializerMethodField`. That would definetly work.